# My program that writes to network drive after many hours fails, how to recover using ofstream?

Tags: c++, ofstream

My program fails to keep writing to file after a few hours and would like to see if I can detect that and possible repoen file or just start a new one.  Should I just check if fail() is true, and if so repoen file?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get specific error codes from std::ofstream, only whether an operation has succeeded or not, so if you need to look for a specific error code (probably) you may need to fall back to platform specific interfaces.

What you can or should do however is to check the return values from operator<<(), std::ofstream::write() and std::ofstream::flush(), for example like this:

```
std::ofstream of("...");
if (! (of << data))
{
   retryOpenfile();
   return;
}
```

If a write operation fails you can retry to open the file and proceed if possible.

Comment: if return value of << is negative, would that be the same as checking fail()?